# Read a list (Array{Any, 1}) from a file in Julia?

Tags: io, julia, readdlm

`readdlm` returns `Array{Any, 2}`, with two dimensions. The file I am reading contains a one-dimensional list, with one item per line. Is there a way to coerce `readdlm` into returning `Array{Any, 1}` (replacing `Any` with an appropriate type)? Or maybe there is a different function for this?

Comment: What is wrong with just wrapping the call with `vec()`? ie `vec(readdlm(filePath, delim, OutputType))`

Comment: @ColinTBowers Will that create a new copy of the array?

Comment: Not sure. I'm not very good at interpreting the output of `@code_llvm`. You could try `@code_llvm randn(100, 1)` and compare it to `@code_llvm vec(randn(100, 1))` - you might be better at this sort of stuff than me. I can say with a fair bit of confidence that you are *very* unlikely to notice any performance difference except in bizarre edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

The `readlines` function will read all the lines of a file:

```
readlines("filename")
```

Be aware that this leaves newlines, which you possibly do not want, and returns strings instead of inferring the type automatically. You may want to parse the data:

```
map(x -> parse(Float64, x), readlines("filename"))
```

replacing `Float64` with the desired type.

Comment: `readlines("filename")` if one entry per line - no issue with newline char

Comment: Indeed, the default has changed to `chomp=true` in the latest version. At the time this answer was written, newlines were preserved.